# Running "ProcessBuilder.start" on Docker fails

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-run

Installation of `libreoffice` package in Docker container.

I'm trying to convert a JAVA application from Excel to a PDF file, but an error occurs.
(The container is running on Google Cloud Run.)

The Dockerfile is below.

```
FROM maven:3.8-jdk-11

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install libreoffice
RUN mvn package

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

The java code running in the container is below.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "soffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir '/out' '/out/file.xlsx'");
Process process = builder.start();
```

The error message that is output is as follows.

```
line 1: soffice:not found
```

After installing the package in the Dockerfile, when I executed the which command, `usr/bin/libreoffice` existed, so I think the path is correct. (I may be wrong)

I'm thinking that there might be information that's missing but I'm not so sure since I'm a newbie with Docker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this ? https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=55868

Comment: Try /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin

Answer (score 1):

The error says that `/bin/sh` does not know where the binary `soffice` is. The "soffice" binary must be on the PATH for `/bin/sh`. Launch a shell and check with `which soffice`, you may be able to fix your shell profile to include the correct PATH directories for soffice before your code will work:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "soffice --headless -convert-to pdf --outdir '/out' '/out/file.xlsx'");
```

But if you know the fully qualified path to the soffice binary you should be able to eliminate the use of sub-process shell and separate the command line arguments:

```
String soffice = "/full/path/to/soffice"; // eg /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin
// Check with:
System.out.println(soffice +" exists: "+new File(soffice).exists());
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(soffice, "--headless", "-convert-to pdf", "--outdir", "/out", "/out/file.xlsx");
```

If "soffice" is in the PATH provided to your JVM, then launch without sub-process shell and path ought to work. You may be able to check `which soffice` before launching your Java application to see if this may work:

```
String soffice = "soffice"; 
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(soffice, "--headless", "-convert-to pdf", "--outdir", "/out", "/out/file.xlsx");
```

Comment: I mentioned where the real binary is on Debian-based systems above

Comment: @g00se Thanks, I've added your suggestion. I don't use Docker or Linux soffice to know.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I got this error when I tried this.
`ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice", "--headless", "-convert-to pdf", "--outdir", "/out", "/out/file.xlsx");`
`Cannot run program "usr/lib/libreoffice":error=2, No such file or directory`

Comment: I also tried.
`ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice", "--headless", "-convert-to pdf", "--outdir", "/out", "/out/file.xlsx");`
`line 1: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice :not found`

I checked to see if this directory(``/usr/lib/libreoffice``) existed and it didn't

Comment: Is your Docker file not working properly?

Comment: @ymd Does your program print "exists: true" in the second example when using the executable directly without `{"/bin/sh", "-c"}`?

Comment: Perhaps a different/incorrect Libre install. Try the brute force ```sudo find / -type f -executable -name \*soffice\* 2>/dev/null``` to find it. Prefer the one ending in .bin